# How to remove account from geary

Tags: pantheon-mail

I have logged into my gmail account from geary. When I tried to remove, I don't find any option to remove. I have only one account in geary.

How to remove user acount(s) from geary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple workaround for this is:

Removing the accounts in `~/.local/share/pantheon-mail`

If you have *only one* account:

Open terminal and run-

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/pantheon-mail/*
```

If you have more than one, Geary *may* provide option to delete the account. Because geary doesn't allow you to remove the final account.

If you don't have the option to remove,

```
cd ~/.local/share/pantheon-mail
ls
```

Now identify the account you want to delete and run:

```
rm -rf account-name
```

Answer (score 2):

Just tried this with the latest Geary, and you have to in effect remove two directories for it to work:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/geary/<account_name>
```

and

```
rm -rf ~/.config/geary/<account_name>
```